# How to publish an any element from envelop schema to MessageBox

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an envelope message (EM), in this EM there some elements which are promoted on the context (for routing) and there is one Any element (called Payload) holding the actual schema instance for further use (other orchestrations are subscribing to that Payload instance).

This is a generic service (WCF, request-response) receiving the request message, returning a response message (having some elements of the request and with a new generated unique transaction ID) and a fault message (when applicable).

The Payload must be published on the MessageBox (direct binding) with some of context properties of the EM.

How can this be done most effectivly ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about how to process envelope schemas using an xml disassembler component inside a receive pipeline? It is not clear from your question if you have tried this or not or if this is even the challenge you are facing.

If not then read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546772(v=BTS.20).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can I just confirm

1. WCF client sends a message matching the Envelope Schema
2. You wish to debatch the Envelope Schema into one or more Payload messages contained inside for the Payload processing orchestration.
3. ? Do you need to wait until all Payload messages are processed until you respond back to the WCF client with a success / fail response (i.e. the response is dependent on the completion of the Payload messages).

If you don't need point 3) then your WCF orchestration can just send a 'yes' message back to the WCF client without worrying about what happens to your payload.

The standard XMLReceive on your WCF Receive location should be able to debatch the message automagically as long as it recognises it as an Envelope schema, i.e. contains

```
<b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns:b="somexmlns"/>
<b:recordInfo body_xpath="xpathtoroot"/>
```

However, if you do need point 3 a problem I can see is that because you are using WCF request-response, is that the client is going to want a synchronous response back depending on the Payload processing. It would be difficult to do this using the standard envelope debatching as you would need to correlate the progress and results of your payload processing back to your WCF orch  - instead, you might just keep your outer (Envelope) schema as non-envelope, and use a custom receive pipeline in your WCF orch to split out the messages and then loop through each and call your payload processing Orchestration.

http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2008/12/debatching-biztalk-xml-messages.html